# Inverting a matrix followed by modulus

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to work through this: https://www.ajer.org/papers/v6(06)/ZB0606212217.pdf

Stuck on this line at the bottom of 214:

$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 5\\ 
1 & 6 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
B^{-1} =
\frac{1}{13}
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -5\\ 
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}mod27
$$

Inverted, OK so far

$$
25
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -5\\ 
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
mod27
$$

How does 1/13 convert into 25?  I'm surely missing something obvious?  It doesn't seem to be modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's working modulo $27$. Then we have $13\cdot 25=1\pmod{27}$ since $12\cdot 25\equiv 13\cdot -2\equiv -26\equiv 1$.

Depending on the context, this is sort of an abuse of notation. Since $27$ isn't prime, $\Bbb Z/27$ is not a field, so we don't no a priori that $13$ has an inverse. However, since it does, it seems reasonable to write $\frac{1}{13}$ for the multiplicative inverse.